# Recursive Sequences (Arithmetic Sequence)

Tags: combinatorics

Given sequence $$9,14,19,24,29,…$$ with $$a_1=9$$

The recursive definition is $$a_n=a_{n−1}+5$$

Closed formula for the sequence is $$a_n=4+5n$$

The sum of $$9+14+19+24+29+⋯+659$$ is $$43754$$ based on the formula for sum of nth term for arithmetic sequence.

The question is, use the above information to find $$b_n$$, the nth term of $$3,12,26,45,69,…$$ where $$b_0=3$$.

Why the answer of $$b_n=n(12+bn)/2$$ is wrong?

Comment: The answer is wrong because according to your formula $b_0 = 0(...) = 0$. It is not $3$ as required.